# Using Conda develop to add source code modules doesn't resolve conda packages

Tags: python, linux, conda

I have a requirement to import a dependency using it's source directory. (Names are obfuscated because this is for work).

So I used `conda develop` which adds a conda.pth file in site-packages

```
[user@user folder]$ conda develop /path/to/source/
added /path/to/source/
completed operation for: /path/to/source/
```

The new module resolves, when I run the code using `python.py`, but then it doesn't resolve dependencies in conda itself. ie:

```
(dq) [user@user]$ python file.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 10, in <module>
    import utils as utils
*...
Various stack trace with import getting resolved
...*
    import Pyro.errors
ImportError: No module named errors
```

So Pyro is a package installed in the dq conda environment, but for some reason through the source code imported through `conda develop`, it can't find the import. I'm not sure if this itself is an issue, but the developer of the code also had the ingenious idea of naming the module `Pyro.py` and then importing `Pyro.errors` at the top of the module. Is there a way to have conda imports take precedence over the source code? Or be resolved in the first place?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Did you install your source module in the `dq` environment? Also, what is `python.py`? And what do you mean by "dependencies in conda itself"? It is also likely that if the file you're running is named `Pyro.py`, then the error is caused by that, as you mention.

Comment: `python.py` is the module that runs a flask app. Trust me, I'd love to just change the name of that stupid module but I can't, it's another code base on a shared drive.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should change the package of Python you work with to another newer or older one from the ***Conda*** page shown by *Jupyter* as shown in this [image: photo].